# Boost Asio and OpenSSL 1.1.0

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake, openssl

I am currently working on a C++ IMAP library so that I can improve on some admittedly rusty C++ skills. I would like to make the library as portable as possible so that I can use it across OS's and, if I'm feeling crazy, maybe even on a mobile device.  To that end, I've done some research and decided to use Boost's Asio library.

I was able to get Boost to build and run in my project by itself. I event made a simple HTTP GET to google.com. Unfortunately, I need to be able to communicate using TLS and I've run into issues trying to use Asio's SSL functionality.

I built both Boost and OpenSSL from source, using default settings (so everything is in /usr/local).  I am also using CMAKE to build my project.  Below is my CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(IMAP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

message(WARNING "Starting CMAKE...")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(IMAP ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread regex REQUIRED)
message(WARNING "Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(WARNING "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
message(WARNING "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(IMAP ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
message(WARNING "OpenSSL_VERSION: ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
message(WARNING "OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(WARNING "OpenSSL_LIBRARIES: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(IMAP ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

And this is the output of my CMAKE messages:

```
Warning:Starting CMAKE...
Warning:Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/local/include
Warning:Boost_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.dylib
Warning:Boost_VERSION: 106100
Warning:OpenSSL_VERSION: 1.1.0
Warning:OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/local/include
Warning:OpenSSL_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

When I try to build the project I receive the following pile of errors:

```
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:43:23: error: expected unqualified-id
    mutexes_.resize(::CRYPTO_num_locks());
                      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/crypto.h:218:41: note: expanded from macro 'CRYPTO_num_locks'
#  define CRYPTO_num_locks()            (0)
                                        ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:46:66: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(&do_init::openssl_locking_func);
                                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:47:56: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::CRYPTO_set_id_callback(&do_init::openssl_id_func);
                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:64:32: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::CRYPTO_set_id_callback(0);
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:65:37: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(0);
                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:66:7: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::ERR_free_strings();
      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/err.h:241:29: note: expanded from macro 'ERR_free_strings'
# define ERR_free_strings() while(0) continue
                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:68:7: warning: 'ERR_remove_thread_state' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ::ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);
      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/err.h:244:25: note: 'ERR_remove_thread_state' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(void ERR_remove_thread_state(void *))
                        ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:72:7: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::EVP_cleanup();
      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h:865:25: note: expanded from macro 'EVP_cleanup'
#  define EVP_cleanup() while(0) continue
                        ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:73:7: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/crypto.h:206:39: note: expanded from macro 'CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data'
# define CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data() while(0) continue
                                      ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:76:7: error: expected unqualified-id
    ::ENGINE_cleanup();
      ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/engine.h:508:27: note: expanded from macro 'ENGINE_cleanup'
# define ENGINE_cleanup() while(0) continue
                          ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:100:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:106:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CRYPTO_LOCK'
    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
               ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:83:31: error: no member named 'SSLv2_method' in the global namespace
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_method());
                            ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:86:31: error: no member named 'SSLv2_client_method' in the global namespace
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_client_method());
                            ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:89:31: error: no member named 'SSLv2_server_method' in the global namespace
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_server_method());
                            ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:111:31: warning: 'TLSv1_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1556:45: note: 'TLSv1_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_method(void)) /* TLSv1.0 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:114:31: warning: 'TLSv1_client_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_client_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1558:45: note: 'TLSv1_client_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_client_method(void)) /* TLSv1.0 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:117:31: warning: 'TLSv1_server_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_server_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1557:45: note: 'TLSv1_server_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_server_method(void)) /* TLSv1.0 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:130:31: warning: 'TLSv1_1_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_1_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1562:45: note: 'TLSv1_1_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_1_method(void)) /* TLSv1.1 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:133:31: warning: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_1_client_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1564:45: note: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_1_client_method(void)) /* TLSv1.1 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:136:31: warning: 'TLSv1_1_server_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_1_server_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1563:45: note: 'TLSv1_1_server_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_1_server_method(void)) /* TLSv1.1 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:148:31: warning: 'TLSv1_2_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_2_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1568:45: note: 'TLSv1_2_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_method(void)) /* TLSv1.2 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:151:31: warning: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_2_client_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1570:45: note: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_client_method(void)) /* TLSv1.2 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:154:31: warning: 'TLSv1_2_server_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::TLSv1_2_server_method());
                              ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1569:45: note: 'TLSv1_2_server_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_server_method(void)) /* TLSv1.2 */
                                            ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:208:16: error: member access into incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' (aka 'ssl_ctx_st')
    if (handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata)
               ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of 'ssl_ctx_st'
typedef struct ssl_ctx_st SSL_CTX;
               ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:212:20: error: member access into incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' (aka 'ssl_ctx_st')
            handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata);
                   ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of 'ssl_ctx_st'
typedef struct ssl_ctx_st SSL_CTX;
               ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:212:22: error: expected ')'
            handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata);
                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:211:53: note: to match this '('
        static_cast<detail::password_callback_base*>(
                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:214:14: error: member access into incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' (aka 'ssl_ctx_st')
      handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata = 0;
             ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of 'ssl_ctx_st'
typedef struct ssl_ctx_st SSL_CTX;
               ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:551:18: error: member access into incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' (aka 'ssl_ctx_st')
          handle_->default_passwd_callback,
                 ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of 'ssl_ctx_st'
typedef struct ssl_ctx_st SSL_CTX;
               ^
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/main.cpp:4:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/IMAPClient.h:6:
In file included from /path/to/my/code/JMail/IMAP/TLSSocket.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:786:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:552:18: error: member access into incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' (aka 'ssl_ctx_st')
          handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata) };
                 ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:144:16: note: forward declaration of 'ssl_ctx_st'
typedef struct ssl_ctx_st SSL_CTX;
               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
10 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

The TLSSocket class that is being referenced is basically just a wrapper around the Boost Asio SSL example:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

void TLSSocket::connect() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(this->address, this->port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);
    mSocket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(io_service, ctx);
    mSocket->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    mSocket->set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&TLSSocket::on_verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));
    boost::asio::async_connect(mSocket->lowest_layer(), iterator,
        boost::bind(&TLSSocket::on_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    io_service.run();
}

void TLSSocket::disconnect() {
    mSocket->lowest_layer().cancel();
}

TLSSocket::TLSSocket(std::string address, std::string port) {
    this->address = address;
    this->port = port;
    mSocket = nullptr;
}

void *TLSSocket::send(IMAPRequest *request) {
    boost::asio::streambuf requestBuff;
    std::ostream request_stream(&requestBuff);
    request_stream << request->getTag() << " " << request->getCommand() << " " << request->getContent() << "\r\n";

    boost::asio::write(*mSocket, requestBuff);

    for (; ;) {
        boost::array<char, 128> buffer;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = mSocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), error);

        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            break;
        else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);

        std::cout.write(buffer.data(), len);
    }
}

void TLSSocket::on_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error){
    if(!error) {
        try {
            mSocket->async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type ::client,
                                     boost::bind(&TLSSocket::on_handshake, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        } catch (std::exception ex){
            std::cout << "Handshaking error: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Connect error: " << error.message() << "\n";
    }
}

void TLSSocket::on_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error){
    if(!error){

    } else {
        std::cout << "Handshaking error: " << error.message() << "\n";
    }
}

bool TLSSocket::on_verify_certificate(bool verified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context &ctx) {
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

    return verified;
}
```

It looks to me like it isn't even getting to the linking stage of compilation, it's just trying to make the .o file for my main.cpp. If I open one of the files that it complains about in my IDE, the IDE gives me a syntax error highlight, but I'm stumped as to why.

Did I put the includes in the wrong order? Is there an issue with my CMAKE file? Did I build OpenSSL or Boost incorrectly?

Any help would be appreciated. I've been working on this on and off for a couple of weeks and have spent the majority of that time just getting it to build (C++ Lesson 1, I guess :)).

Comment: Now open on OpenSSL's RT... [Issue 4547: Changing function CRYPTO_num_locks() to "#define CRYPTO_num_locks() (0)" breaks compiles](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4547&user=guest&pass=guest). The project may be able to ease the pain; or they may suggest guarding based on versioning and alternate code paths. If OpenSSL suggests the latter, then you will need to open a bug report with Boost. Its not uncommon for OpenSSL to break programs due to symbol changes on minor version bumps (i.e., 1.0.2 to 1.1.0). Their governance may allow it, but I did not go looking for the policy docs.

Comment: I ended up rolling back to 1.0.2 and everything worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Now open in the Boost bug tracker... [Issue 12238: Boost fails to compile using OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12238)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks to me like Boost has not been updated to work with OpenSSL 1.1.0. There have been a number of API changes between OpenSSL 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 and they are not fully source compatible. I suggest you use 1.0.2 until Boost has been updated to work with the new OpenSSL version (which is still in beta anyway).

Comment: That worked! You have no idea how much time you've saved me.  Thanks a ton!