# VS2015 build openssl with boost asio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, openssl

I am compiling with **Visual studio 2015** and **Boost v1.61** and **OpenSSL v"1.1.0-pre7-dev"** (from [OpenSSL Github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl)). In accordance with what is said in the **INSTALL** file, I installed the OpenSSL like that (for the **debug** mod):

```
$ perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=D:/OpenSSL/build/debug --debug
$ nmake
$ nmake test
$ nmake install
```

In the project setting, I added :

- The include directory path in the "C/C++ - General "(D:/OpenSSL/build/debug/include)
- The lib directory (D:/OpenSSL/build/debug/lib) in the "linker - general - other dependencies"

I use the **c++ boost asio SSL** library but when I build the project I have this error (see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ipcEGWSs) for the full output):

```
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(43): error C2589: '(' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(43): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(46): error C2589: ';' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(46): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(47): error C2589: ';' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(47): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(64): error C2589: ';' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(64): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(65): error C2589: ';' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(65): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(66): error C2589: 'while' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(66): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(72): error C2589: 'while' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(72): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(73): error C2589: 'while' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(73): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(76): error C2589: 'while' : jeton non conforme à droite de '::'
1>d:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp(76): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '::'
...
```

I noticed that even if I omits to add the lib directory in the linker I have the same error.

Why am I getting the compile error?

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to the jww's answer, indeed, the 1.1.0 version of OpenSSL is incompatible with the current version of Boost. I downloaded the OpenSSL 1.0.2h and this works well.

Comment: Also see [Boost Asio and OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37517730) on Stack Overflow and [Issue 12238: Boost fails to compile using OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12238) on the Boost bug tracker. You may have additional issues, but that one seems to be a show stopper.