# Asio dependency on OpenSSL

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

While implementing code for SSL Handshake using Asio, the project does not build and throws error

> C:\Eclipse\Boost\boost_1_62_0/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:19:26:    fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory

So does it mean that for SSL using Asio we need to install OpenSSL ?

Well that's not the point i wanted to raise. The question is, is there any other alternate to use Asio SSL without asking client to install OpenSSL or in other words how can I statically bind OpenSSL with my application in a single executable?

Comment: Yes you have to install OpenSSL for boost. Do you mean you want to use OpenSSL + Boost without installing it (OpenSSL) ?

Comment: You need to provide more information, like how you configured and built Boost, and how you are building your program. Also see [Boost Asio and OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37517730), [VS2015 build openssl with boost asio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39032716) and [Issue 12238: Boost fails to compile using OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12238).

Comment: Correct,, I want to make an executable that allows client to communicate without any need to install OpenSSL on Client Side @Blacktempel

Comment: Yes Boost haven't been updated to work with OpenSSL 1.1.0 that's not an issue I will use the older version  OpenSSL 1.0.2 , Thanks :) @jww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I statically bind OpenSSL with my application in a single executable?

Yes.   You can build openssl with the `no-shared` option and it will only build a static library:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation

and then just put the static archive on your link command line and it will be statically linked - but the people you distribute it to do not.

However, for you to link the program you have to have the header files and static library available to your compiler/linker.

Answer (score 7):

`boost::asio` uses `OpenSSL`for `SSL` sockets: if you have:

```
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
```

in your code, then you'll need to build with `OpenSSL` as well as `boost`.

To build with `OpenSSL`:

- define the macro `BOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS` at project level;
- add the `OpenSSL` include directory to your include path;
- add the `OpenSSL` library directory to your library path, e.g. `-L$${OPENSSL_ROOT}/lib`;
- add the appropriate crypto libraries for your compiler, e.g.:

Windows, Visual Studio:

```
LIBS += -llibeay32
LIBS += -llibssleay32
```

Windows, MinGW:

```
LIBS += -lssl
LIBS += -lcrypto
```

Linux, GCC:

```
LIBS += -lssl
LIBS += -lcrypto
LIBS += -ldl
```

Note: you may have link issues with library order. I recommend including the `OpenSSL` libraries after the `boost` libraries; BTW `boost::asio` requires `libboost_system`.

Comment: for windows also link with crypt32.lib